# Why can I not remove "[restr=戸]" with this pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have string like this one:

```
"
[2][n]
  shutter; window shutter

,と|戸,1266970,(Y, 5, 3, Y, [1][n]
  [restr=戸]
  door (esp. Japanese-style)"
```

I am trying to remove `[restr=戸]`

With this code:

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\n  )?\[(see|note|ant|restr|syn)=[^\]]*\]]");
 var m1 = regex.Replace(m, "");
```

But when I look at m1 the string is still there.

Can anyone see why it's not removing the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it'd be best to do that replace on `s` mode, with some simple expression, maybe similar to,

```
\s*\[\s*\b(?:see|note|ant|restr|syn)\b\s*=[^\]]*\]
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R427q7/1/)

#### Test 1

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"\s*\[\s*\b(?:see|note|ant|restr|syn)\b\s*=[^\]]*\]";
        string substitution = @"";
        string input = @"[2][n]
          shutter; window shutter

        ,と|戸,1266970,(Y, 5, 3, Y, [1][n]
          [restr=戸]
          door (esp. Japanese-style)";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Singleline;

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

#### Test 2

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?s)\s*\[\s*\b(?:see|note|ant|restr|syn)\b\s*=[^\]]*\]";
        string substitution = @"";
        string input = @"[2][n]
          shutter; window shutter

        ,と|戸,1266970,(Y, 5, 3, Y, [1][n]
          [restr=戸]
          door (esp. Japanese-style)";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

#### [C# Demo](https://ideone.com/8AnBKe)

#### Output

```
[2][n]
  shutter; window shutter

,と|戸,1266970,(Y, 5, 3, Y, [1][n]
  door (esp. Japanese-style)
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1Q1HP5/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/1Q1HP5/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the last `]` as it will require a second closing `]`, and I also recommend matching both CRLF or LF endings (in case you can have Windows or Unix line endings), and enhance the horizontal whitespace part:

```
var m1 = Regex.Replace(m, @"(?:\r?\n[\p{Zs}\t]*)?\[(?:see|note|ant|restr|syn)=[^]]*]", "");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%5b%5cp%7bZs%7d%5ct%5d*%29%3f%5c%5b%28%3f%3asee%7cnote%7cant%7crestr%7csyn%29%3d%5b%5e%5d%5d*%5d&i=%0d%0a%5b2%5d%5bn%5d%0d%0a++shutter%3b+window+shutter%0d%0a%0d%0a%2c%e3%81%a8%7c%e6%88%b8%2c1266970%2c%28Y%2c+5%2c+3%2c+Y%2c+%5b1%5d%5bn%5d%0d%0a++%5brestr%3d%e6%88%b8%5d%0d%0a++door+%28esp.+Japanese-style%29)

**Details**

- `(?:\r?\n[\p{Zs}\t]*)?` - an optional sequence of
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(?:see|note|ant|restr|syn)` - either `see`, `note`, `ant`, `restr` or `syn` char sequences
- `=` - a `=` char
- `[^]]*` - 0 or more chars other than `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.